# WhatsApp Tracking Extract fails to run

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, journeybuilder

Currently there is no available analytical report regarding WhatsApp messages in Marketing Cloud.

The only [WhatsApp report that Marketing Cloud provides](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_whatsapp_data_extract.htm&type=5)
is not working right now, according to this Known Issue:
[WhatsApp Tracking Extract fails to run](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=whatsapp-tracking-extract-fails-to-run&Id=a1p4V000001U5PY).

So if I activate my WhatsApp journey right now, I will not be able to know what happened to each message I sent.

How many contacts from the initial DE received my messages? how many answered? What did they answer? How long did they take to answer it? How many unsubscribed? How many Blocked?

Without this kind of information I can´t activate the journey, because is crucial for me to get these information.

I questioned my AE and he replied me that the Technology team were working on a fix for this and that they should have gone live with it already. Does anyone have a work around for this issue?